# JSoup: How to select first table in page containing multiple tables

Tags: java, dom, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to select and parse a page containing multiple tables using JSoup.

I only need the first table.

When I do:

```
System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTag("table"));
```

It prints out all the tables in the page.
The tables do not have any unique identifier to differentiate between them and the classes are also same.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `first()` method:

```
doc.getElementsByTag("table").first();
```